# How to aggregate the result of bash sort on multiple files into a single file?

Tags: shell, sorting, unique, aggregate, word-frequency

I have a `~90GB` file. Each line consists of tab-separated pairs such as `Something \t SomethingElse`. My main goal is to find the frequency of each unique line in the file. So I tried

`sort --parallel=50 bigFile | unique -c > new_sortedFile`

which did not work due to the file size. Then I split the original big file into 9 parts (each 10 GB) then the same command worked for each file separately.

So my question is how can I aggregate the result of those 9 files into a single file in order to have the same result of the bigFile?

Comment: `sort -m new{1..9}` maybe?

Comment: Surely you want `uniq` not `unique`